# How to create item shadow in RadListView?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

How is it possible to achieve item shadows in a RadListView? To have a shadow of each item and the shadow is not stripped between the items or on the side paddings.

Answer (score 1):

*For Android:*

XML:

```
<lv:RadListView xmlns:lv="nativescript-ui-listview" loaded="listLoaded">
    <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
        <StackLayout loaded="itemLoaded">
            ...
        </StackLayout>
    </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
</lv:RadListView>
```

JS:

```
function listLoaded(args) {
    var list = args.object;
    list.androidListView.setClipToPadding(false);
    list.androidListView.setClipChildren(false);
}

function itemLoaded(args) {
    var item = args.object;
    item.nativeView.setOutlineProvider(android.view.ViewOutlineProvider.BOUNDS);
    item.nativeView.setClipToOutline(false);
}

exports.listLoaded = listLoaded;
exports.itemloaded = itemLoaded;
```

This creates a nics unstripped shadow to every direction:
[image]